# Getting all list of items and passing it into an array

Tags: swift

I am working on a project and I am trying get a list of items and return it into an array to use in my project.

This is my code:

```
let identifier = delete.items

var identifiers: [String] = []
identifier.forEach({ (listModel) in
    identifiers = ["\(String(describing: listModel.remiderDate))"]
})

print("ITEMS DATES \(String(describing: identifiers.count))")
```

The `identifier` returns an array of values not reminderDate alone but I am focused on getting the `reminderDate`.

Printing the identifies returns `1` whereas the number expected to return 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop assigns a new value to `identifiers` each time so only the last value remains.

You probably want to use `map`:

```
let identifiers = delete.items.map { String(describing: $0.reminderDate) }
print("ITEMS DATES \(identifiers.count)")
```

Please note that using `String(describing:)` should only be used for debugging. Use a `DateFormatter` to convert a `Date` to a `String`.